# Initialize DataRow object with DataGridView Selected row

Tags: c#, window

Window c# Desktop Application

I want to initialize a `DataRow object` with the selected row of `DataGrdView`.

Is it possible if yes then how?

I am writting the followind code and it is giving compilation error.

```
DataRow dr = (DataRow)DataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DataRow dr = (DataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DataRow dr = (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
```

Comment: According to my browser you were 17 secs faster than me :)